# Does Idisposable get called on stack items like struct (when not using "Using")

Tags: c#, struct, idisposable

Leaving aside whether it's a horrendous terrible idea to ever implement `IDisposable`  on a non-reference type, would the `Dispose()` method get called when a non-reference `IDisposable` is removed from the stack?

Comment: Nope i mean IDisposable.Dispose

Comment: Why on earth you want IDisposable struct?

Comment: Canonical link: https://ericlippert.com/2011/03/14/to-box-or-not-to-box/

Comment: @dotctor For the exact same reasons you'd want a disposable reference type.  It has unmanaged resources to clean up.

Comment: I'm aware of the boxing problem i'm not dealing with an unmanaged resource. Using more for cleaning non used (cached) dictionary items

Comment: @AlexKrupka If you have references inside of your `struct` it should probably be a class instead.  If you don't have unmanaged resources, or a reference to an `IDisposable` type then you don't need to make your struct/class disposable in the first place.

Comment: I'm implementing a lock generation class that provides a object to lock-on based on the requested key. In order to keep the dictionary from getting too large I need a way of keeping track of what threads have refs to the object I'm using a struct to wrap the object so that on its dispose it removes its "ref" (stored in keyvaluepair<object,Hashset<Guid>>) to the object and if there are no other refs removes from dictionary (concurrent - with locking to make sure no adds to hashset)

Comment: I should add that its not the end of the world if the object remains in the dictionary this is just to keep memory allocation down

Comment: @AlexKrupka Then you're doing the wrong thing.  You're spending more memory trying to save memory than you'd spend creating the objects when you need them.

Comment: @Servy No. There are potentially an infinite amount of keys that can be called only a limited amount of threads to do the calling

Comment: @AlexKrupka That doesn't change the fact that you're better off just re-creating objects when you need them than trying to keep them around for re-use.

Comment: @Servy my bad for not explaining properly. The object is being used for the locking. Each key needs its own lock so i need a way for dif thread to lock if they are updating the same key. So i need persistence of objects as long as any thread is ref it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: NO,

Merely creating a struct that lives on the stack will NOT cause `Dispose()` to be called when it goes out of scope. (Of course, neither will that happen for a class.)

`Dispose()` will only be called if it is called explicitly, or if it is called implicitly through a `using`.

However, `Dispose()` *will* be called if a struct implements `IDisposable` and is used inside a using, like so:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    struct Test: IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Help! Help! I'm being oppressed!");
        }
    }
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var test = new Test())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Using a Test object");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
Using a Test object
Help! Help! I'm being oppressed!
```

Note that structs are generally intended to be lightweight, and shouldn't really contain references (except perhaps for strings). In that case, a struct shouldn't have anything disposable in it, so this question wouldn't arise.

Comment: The OP is asking if it will be disposed if he *doesn't* dispose of it himself, not if it'll be disposed if he disposes it.

Comment: @Servy Give me a minute, I'm still writing the answer :)

Comment: If you weren't done with your answer you shouldn't have posted it.

Comment: So the answer should be No!

Comment: @Servy I posted, then realised that I had omitted some information, so I edited it then.

Comment: I think OP is primarily concerned with the "non-using" case.  Your answer should probably start off "The answer is: no.  Dispose will only be called when utilizing a using...."